# val.slice is not a function error in ionic 3 angular 4 application

Tags: angular, ionic3, ngx-datatable

I am getting val.slice is not a function error while i am trying to implement ngx-datatable in ionic 3 angular 4 application. please find the code part below

```
app.module.ts:

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HeaderMenuComponent } from '../components/header-menu/header-menu';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { TodolistPage } from '../pages/todolist/todolist';

import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    TodolistPage,
    SignupPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxDatatableModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    TodolistPage
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AuthServiceProvider,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

to-do-list.html:

```
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>To-do List</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <div>
    <ngx-datatable
    [sortType]="'multi'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="50"
    [rows]="rows"
    [columns]="columns"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [limit]="10">
  </ngx-datatable>
  </div>


</ion-content>
```

to-do-list.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../../providers/auth-service';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-todolist',
  templateUrl: 'todolist.html',
})
export class TodolistPage {

  public columns: any;
  public rows: any;
 public error: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public authService: AuthServiceProvider) {
   this.columns = [
      { prop : 'name' },
      { name : 'ID' },
      { name : 'Username'},
      { name : 'Email ID'}
    ];
    this.getUsers();  //runs on page load
  }


  getUsers() {
    this.authService.getData('getFeed').then((result) => {  
      //console.log(result);  
      this.rows = result;
    },(err) => {
      this.error =err;
      alert(this.error);
    });
  }

}
```

And my service file to get data:

auth-service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Header } from 'ionic-angular/components/toolbar/toolbar-header';

let apiUrl = "http://localhost/PHP-Rest/api/";


@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
  }


  getData(type){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     let headers = new Headers();
     this.http.get(apiUrl+type,{headers: headers}).subscribe(res => {
       resolve(res.json());
     }, (err) => {
       reject(err);
     });
  })
}

}
```

For this program I am getting a JSON output as follows,

[image]

I didn't find anything wrong and I am new to ionic angular. Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

val.slice is not a function error in ionic 3 angular 4 application

Comment: where are you calling val.slice?

Comment: I didn't call val.slice function anywhere. It is in the ngx-datatable library file.

Comment: I have installed ngx-datatable in my ionic 3 angular 4 project using the following command                                                                                    
                                "npm i @swimlane/ngx-datatable --save"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the error you see happens when the data you try to render in the table is not “iterateable” type like Array.

So in your case you have the object { feedData: [...array of objects...] }

And you need it to be: [...array of objects...]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is working perfect. You saved my day.